# Why is this reaction deprotonated with CH3OH?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

[image]

Why is this reaction deprotonated with CH3OH and not water?

Comment: Shouldn't MeOH be more basic than water? Just from the first look at it I would expect higher substituted alcohols to be more basic...

Comment: E.g. isopropanol, tert-butanol would be even more basic.

Comment: It would generally be helpful to provide the source you are referring to. By the way, I wouldn't post copyrighted material like this ...

Comment: It doesn't matter whether methanol or water deprotonates it considering that they have almost the same basicity. If there's more MeOH lying around then it's more likely to be deprotonated by MeOH, if there's more H2O lying around then it's more likely to be deprotonated by H2O.

Answer (score 1):

Pka of water is 15.7
Pka of methanol is 16

In the end, methanol should be protonated somehow. But the truth is, in solution both water and methanol could theoretically donated the proton in the first step. And both water and methanol could accept the proton in the last step.

When I took organic chemistry, as long as we showed the complete electron exchange, water could be excluded or included entirely.